# Sequence of foreign keys

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have an object type SPORTS ARENA that is supposed to lists all the sports held in that arena and an object type  SPORT with all the infos about a sport:

```
SPORTS ARENA
name: string
sports: seq string

SPORT
name: string
disciplines: seq string

SPORTS ARENA <-->> SPORT (1:n) relationship, one sport can be held in only one arena (in this case it is like this) 
and one arena can hold multiple sports.
```

This is an objects scheme and I want to convert it in a relational scheme with primary keys and foreign keys.

Usually in (1:n) relations you put in one table an attribute as foreign key refering the primary key of the other table.

In this case I have to deal with a sequence, so do I have to make an attribute that is a sequence of foreign keys? or how would the relational scheme look like?

Comment: see (external site)
https://www.damirsystems.com/sql-x-to-y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Arena ARE exists.
--
arena {ARE}
   PK {ARE}
```

- *Each sport can be held in exactly one arena;
  for each arena, that arena may hold more than one sport.*

```
-- Sport SPO is held in arena ARE.
--
sport {SPO, ARE}
   PK {SPO}

FK {ARE} REFERENCES arena {ARE}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key
```

Comment: So in this case you removed the sports sequence from the Arena table right? Is that because it is not possible to have a sequence of values that are foreign keys?

Comment: @Mizzet, Each row-column intersection has exactly one element from the column-domain. Meaning: exactly one sport in SPO column, exactly one arena in ARE column. That is, if you want relational.